# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API IIS Hosting and Debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a ASP.NET Core 2 Web API with the Angular 4 front end SPA application. It was created using clean Core 2 Web API template in VS2017 and angular-cli for the front-end using VSCode. Currently I can successfully run my prototype using either IIS Express WebAPI or self-hosted. I can successfully deploy to IIS using steps simmilar to these: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x. However, I can't figure out how to attach to the IIS process to be able to step through the code as I used to do with regular old Web API or MVC app hosted in IIS.

I'm coming from traditional Web API and Angular1 environment. Both ends were deployed to IIS and it was a simple process to attach to IIS for troubleshooting. So, maybe it's a stupid question, but I can't seem to find good resource on how to approach production deployment of such Core 2 WebAPI + Angular 2 SPA app. What are the best practices? IIS for Web API and npm for client? Can someone maybe point me to tutorial on how to do that and how to debug/troubleshoot with IIS? Are there a better ways to deploy/host it, maybe my approach is wrong and IIS not needed?

If any pictures, code, setup is needed I'll gladly add it to the question. I just don't know what I can provide at the moment. Any help, advise, link will be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what is the `500 server error`? Check your console.

Comment: Failed to load resource. The thing is I can't attach even with simple API that runs fine. How the hell I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: I assume on your local development machine you used ng-serve for angular? Which is working because it's hosted using node. What you're missing is web.config for your angular hosted on IIS (URL rewrite strategy).

Comment: Thnx 12secs for such quick response! - Yes, I run ng serve for client. But I'm not even talking about client right now. I'm more concerned about the web api. I don't have web.config naturally, but it gets generated when I publish it (to wwwroot directory but anything really can be used). And as I mentioned - the simple Values api from VS2017 template works fine.

Comment: Also, when I tried just adding config to my WebApi project it didn't work at all.

Comment: You can try using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). I use it as an add-on in chrome. Send a `GET` to your web address. It usually provides a much nicer error report.

Comment: @Lex - That's exactly what I'm trying to figure out - how to troubleshoot this 500. Specifically - how to attach the debugger. I just not sure what to show - code, setup, IIS settings? I already have figured out my setup problem that caused 500, however my main question remains - how to attach/debug the code while IIS hosted.

Comment: @Lex - 500 is fixed. Question is about debugging when IIS hosted

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're after, but check out this blog-post:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/07/13/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/

Note: Make sure you select the new launch profile ("IIS") in the main window, before starting a debug session!

Comment: Installing Development Time IIS Support worked for me.